# How do we know that we will collide with Andromeda?

Tags: collision, galaxies, milky-way

We know that Andromeda galaxy is heading towards the Milky Way. But how do we know that Andromeda doesn't have a large Transverse velocity? This would cause the Milky Way and Andromeda galaxies to either simply miss each other, or potentially even orbit each other.

Could that possibly be the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate/closely related: [How and why will the Milky Way collide with the Andromeda galaxy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/14657/226902) and [Andromeda/Milky Way collision: How, and how accurately, can a galaxy's lateral velocity be measured?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26745/226902)